# HTTPS Firewall always disablen when turned on

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I create a new instance on Google cloud. The VPS is running lamp for my WordPress website. HTTPS port is closed

[This is screenshot on my instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQO2K.png)

When I check on NMAP, https port is closed. So I open my Instance setting and edit the firewall rules. My port still closed

Comment: If you reword your question as a real question it may help you out. e.g. Why can't I get my Google Cloud VPS instance to keep an open https port?  or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I check on NMAP, https port is closed. So I open my Instance
>   setting and edit the firewall rules. My port still closed

Opening a port (HTTPS) in the firewall only allows an external TCP connection thru the firewall. You will need software (service) running inside your VM to accept these connections.

WordPress (Apache) supports two types of protocols: HTTP, which uses port 80 and HTTPS (SSL/TLS), which uses port 443. Those port numbers are conventions and can be changed to support your requirements. For example, HTTP on port 8080 and HTTPS on port 8443.

Depending on your skill level (or desire to learn more), there are a few options to get HTTPS (SSL/TLS) setup on WordPress.

The first method is to use a WordPress Plugin. An example is SSL Zen ([link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ssl-zen/)).

The second method is to use Let's Encrypt to issue an SSL certificate and then you configure Apache for HTTPS. You need intermediate skills with Let's Encrypt and Apache.

The third method is to go to a Certificate Authority and purchase an SSL certificate and then you configure Apache for HTTPS. Some companies will provide technical support (not all) to help you.